# Weird rect element width and height behaviour only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have an SVG consisting of only a single rectangle acting as a frame for a modal, of which the SVG sits on top of. I was doing some testing and noticed that the rectangle was [being cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNXEA.jpg). Bringing up inspector shows the reason: the rectangle element is over [**10,000 times larger than it should be**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQEmO.jpg), despite being given a width and height value of 100% each. And since the SVG viewport is behaving as expected, it cuts off the rest.

[Rechecking the width/height toggles fixes the issue temporarily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYeG7.jpg) - reverting back to the incorrect size when I refresh the page - suggesting that the issue is not with the CSS values itself.

The behaviour is only noticeable in Chrome and works perfectly as expected in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kObo4.jpg) and Safari so it seems as though the issue is with Chrome but I would love some StackOverflow expertise on the matter before I jump to any conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is that I have to pass in width=100% and height=100% in the rect props (as I am using React) as opposed to putting it in CSS, not sure why Chrome has a different behaviour though.